# How can I represent this scenrio using Domain Driven Design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I have been reading up Domain Driven Design and what they talk about seem to be exactly the opposite of what I have been doing the last ten years. Like a normal developer I was with the idea the following was a good clean architecture

> client app -> Remote Facade -> Services Layer -> Data Store.
>   Domain is something that is shared across all different layers

All the DDD experts seem to vehemently oppose this idea. Am trying to wrap my head around applying DDD to a simple problem explained below

Let us say the domain is Human Resources department

The domain (ubiquitous language as they call it) would contain things like

> Employee, Manager, Salary, Bonus, Incentive, WorkHours etc

A store (in my case releational) with tables corresponding to the domain mentioned above

> Table Employee, Table Manager, Table Bonus

Calculations using these domain objects

> CalculateBonus, CalculateWorkHours, CalculateSalary, ProcessPay, CalculateVacationLeft etc.

And ofcourse there is UI, in which the user (what he/she can do is based on roles) can do

> Login, Add a new Employee, Make an employee manager, Add incentive to
>   a manager etc.

I have laid those things out to the best of my knowledge. With that particular context in mind, here are my questions

1. DDD talks about domain and business logic existing together. Does this mean my Domain objects like Employee and Manager should contain logic like (calculateDiscount or calculateVacationLeft)? I have always separated out those logic into some sort of service, is that a bad idea? (Some even go to the extent of saying CRUD can also be part of the domain_
2. What is the business logic in this scenario? Is CalculateBonus() a business logic or application logic? and where should it actually reside?
3. Is applying DDD for a simple problem even worth it?

I wanted this to be a short post, but ended up being long. I hope to have a good discussion around this

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 2):

1. You should always try to place your business logic within the aggregate root it relates to.  If you have some exception to this rule, that involves multiple entities and doesn't really fit in just one of them, then use a domain service.  If all your logic is in domain services then you have what's called an anemic domain model, where your entities are just property bags.  Look into a concept called double dispatch for guidance how to incorporate complex logic within an entity method.
2. CalculateBonus() sounds like business logic to me.  If a domain expert speaks of a concept, then chances are it belongs in the domain layer.  The application layer is there largely to orchestrate domain entities to perform the required use cases for your system.
3. I would avoid DDD whenever you are not in a collaborative environment (such as a user editing his own profile), don't have access to domain experts, or are mainly doing CRUD with little to no true business invariants being enforced.  It is also important to remember, DDD is not an all or nothing concept.  You can use it wherever makes sense in your system.

Comment: I did read about anemic domain model but what they don't seem to talk about is whether having such a model good or bad. Should I strive to move away from it? All my previous years, I have worked hard to keep my domain models with just simple properties and moving away any logic into a domain service layer. This idea seems to radical to me!

Comment: Some people say their are benefits to an anemic domain, while some claim it's an anti-pattern.  Personally I lean towards the benefits of an anemic domain.

Comment: I think why people find it so difficult to encapsulate their behavior within one aggregate root, is that they are modeling their entities like database tables, and they are using one model for the entire application.  You should be using a model only in a bounded context (ie. order processing or shipping).

Comment: It makes a lot of sense when said out loud "bounded context - many models". But when it comes to applying it to a problem, I find it hard to create that context. In the example above, "CalculateIncentives", "CalculateVaction", would those be considered as bounded models?

Comment: Bounded contexts are like sub domains.  So in your case, vacations would probably be in one sub domain and incentives in another.  Also, entities are not just the nouns in your system.  You could have an entity called called EmployeeVacationPolicy, and a method called GetRemainingDays().  When modeling your entities, you must first ask what are the invariants I need to enforce.  Then you must ask questions like, why do you need to calculate vacation days in the first place.  These questions might lead you to discover the true behavior that is hiding, waiting to be modeled.

Comment: Also, it's common and even expect that your entities will have a different "shape" than your database tables.  That is why we abstract data access behind repositories.

Answer (score 2):

1. Logic that just affects a single entity root (or AR) can be put in that entity (or AR).  If it affects that single entity and another entity, the logic should go in a domain service.  You application services are then the driver of your application that would orchestrate a particular workflow, use case, etc. in your domain.
2. CalculateBonus() sound like an operation on one type of entity, maybe involving others.  It would probably belong in a service in the domain model.  If you take the objects you list as your domain, instantly some of these stand out to me as entities that should be children of other entities (making an aggregate root).  When listed as objects/tables in an anaemic model, these loose any domain knowledge, as by looking at a list of anaemic models I can't see how they interact or compose into aggregates.
3. It is probably not worth applying DDD for simple problems, particularly CRUD style admin interfaces.  Applying DDD will take more time.  Overall the benefits with DDD are a system that more closely reflects/documents the domain.  Saying that, there's lots to learn from DDD that can be applied to any application.

It's interesting that you mention that DDD experts see sharing one set of domain entities across all layers as an anti-pattern.  I work with many teams that try to do this and they find themselves in a HUGE mess with just the simplest of applications.  Particularly when they misuse entities generated for, or by, an ORM.

Trying to do this with DDD this would bring database implementation details, not relevant to your domain, up into your domain model.  It also brings too much information up through the layers and when you send this data over-the-wire (via a web service, queue, message bus, etc.) or up to the UI, you're juggling not only too much non-required data, but usually sensitive data and then hacking further things on top to circumvent this sensitive data appearing in the UI.  You end up with situations where a future developer could easily accidentally add sensitive information to an object like Employee and without realising it, this information is then suddenly serialised into JSON and is appearing unprotected (yet hidden) in the JavaScript behind the UI.

Then there's bounded context pollution.  An Employee entity will look different in a HR, shipping, billing, sales, etc. bounded context.  Trying to make a one-size-fits-all entity that suits all bounded contexts (but actually suits none and captures no domain knowledge) is a massive anti-pattern.  I see this daily in the teams I work with, it's still a huge mistake that developers make.  Things like bounded contexts are probably one of the biggest things to come out of DDD that can completely change the way you code for the better.

Another common misunderstanding with DDD is that it is some sort of architectural pattern.  Although there are patterns in the book by Eric Evans about upstream and downstream teams/systems, shared kernels and other things that do relate to architecture, DDD itself is a collection of goodness/patterns to simply help design better systems that better reflect the domain they're attempting to model.

Comment: If I do put behavior inside say those objects, say for example in Employees, I create a method called
CalculateBonus(WorkingHours hours), am I not tightly coupling WorkingHours to Employees? Why is
CalculateBonusServuce(Employee, WorkingHours) not a better solution? This approach lets me change
CalculateBonusSerice() without affecting Employee or WorkingHours, isnt that a good thing?

Comment: Also how do we create these domain objects. Say for example we have a relational database with a physical data model, do we create a thin layer of objects that reflect the tables and then map those into these domain models with behaviour?

Comment: Many thanks for your response btw, am trying to really understand the reasoning behind DDD, pardon me if I sound like am nitpicking

Comment: Comment #1, as the result of `CalculateBonus()` wouldn't effect `Employee` (I'm taking it that you wouldn't want the result stored inside the `Employee` instance)...  I would probably implement `CalculateBonus()` in a domain service.  Particularly because it involves 2 entities (or 1 entity and 1 value object).

Comment: Comment #2, I retrieve objects from my persistence layer (if you're using a typical SQL database, you would most likely use a repository).  I make these calls from application layer, down into the persistence layer.  The repository would return a domain model aggregate (think of aggregates as a single entity, or an object graph/tree of entity/value objects), any mapping from the ORM entity or DTO objects would be done inside the repository method.

Comment: Employee Table and Manager Table is read by the Repository as EmpDTO and ManagerDTO afterwhich I can create Employee AggregateRoot which will have behavious like
GetAllEmployees(), GetEmployeesWhoAreManagers(). UI would then use both EmpDTO's and Employee AR.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look into CQRS to address part of your question.  If you're doing DDD correctly then first you model your domain, with persistence as a secondary concern.  I.e. if I call `EmployeeRepository.CreateNewEmployee(Employee employee)`, I shouldn't care how or where it is persisted.  I try to avoid any `GetAll()` repository methods, they're usually a code smell and might point to problems in your design.